# Workaround for small caps and italic?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, classicthesis, thesis

I'm doing a Thesis with ClassicThesis and ArsClassica, but I'm trying to slightly personalised it.

Basically the main thing is that I've changed the font of the all the title, from Iwona to Palatino (ppl family).

In this style the Table of Contents has the chapters written in all small caps, the problem is that (in only one case) I need to use a Scientific name. A scientific name MUST be Italicised and with the first letter in uppercase (as Homo sapiens).

So first I've tried to reset the option locally with NoCaseChange and textit. This work but the uppercase H is ignored and I get *homo sapiens*. If I exclude the H I obtain H*omo sapiens* and it's quite horrible.

There is a way to solve this without change all of the structure of the Table of Contents? I prefer to not change the font as well, because is consistent in all the figures and in all the thesis.

The better way in my opinion is to have the the small caps in the sentence before, than an italicised Upper Case for the H and a italicised small caps for the omo sapiens part.

How can I do that?

P.S. I've attached what I have now, I'm open to new ideas in order to make something slightly good-looking.

P.P.S Sorry for the bad english but I'm in a hurry for work and it's not my native language.

[image: actual piece from the Table of Contents]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm only guessing as you didn't provide real code, but probably it will work if you protect the command:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{TEXT \protect\NoCaseChange{\textit{Homo sapiens}}}

\end{document}
```

If you want a slanted small caps, you can try pagella (a palatino clone) it has an scit shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}

\scshape ABCabc \fontshape{scit}\selectfont ABCabc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This actually work, many thanks! I've not copied the part with mathptmx because with that the actual font of Table of Contents change. The only thing which I did not try was the \protect.
Now the result is acceptable but in my opinion can be improved.
the question is: there is a way now to have a standard Palatino italicised and in small caps at the same time? If there isn't then the only solution is to use normal text.
Thanks again!

Comment: I added an edit about a slanted small caps.

Comment: Perfect, with tgpagella I can have both small caps and the slanted text. Thanks.